# org.json - StackOverflowError when attempting to parse JSONArray containing html strings

Tags: javascript, java, json, stack-overflow, org.json

I have the latest version of org.json - json-20171018.

In my application, I must create a JSONArray in Java of various fields, which have been created on the front end (javascript) with the assistance of TinyMCE. I have to escape the quotes in the text, otherwise it will not be properly stringified. Upon passing this, as well as other parameters, to the back end, I attempt to parse the JSON.

On the front end:

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < thing.length; i++) {
    var txt = tinyMCE.get("element").getContent();
    txt = txt.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
    //-The text is then encoded for passing to the back end

    object["id"] = id;
    object["text"] = txt;
    object["display_order"] = i;
    //-etc, etc.
    array.push(object);
}
var sArray = { "array" : array };
sArray = JSON.stringify(sArray);

params = "arr="+sArray;
```

This is then passed to the back end. My logging server shows it as follows, in a string:

```
"{\"array\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"text\":\"<p><span style=\\\"font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', cursive;\\\">gfsgsfgsfd</span></p>\",\"correct_answer\":false,\"display_order\":0,\"font\":\"Comic Sans MS\",\"font_size\":\"11pt\"}]}";
//-Or, escaped up a level:
{"array":[{"id":"1","text":"<p><span style=\"font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', cursive;\">gfsgsfgsfd</span></p>","correct_answer":false,"display_order":0,"font":"Comic Sans MS","font_size":"11pt"}]}
```

I take the string and create a JSONObject, which seems to work fine.

```
String sArr = req.getParameter("arr").trim();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sArr);
if (jsonObject.has("array")) { .... }
```

After logging every step of the way, I have determined that the JSONObject does indeed have this array:

```
[{"font_size":"11pt","correct_answer":false,"display_order":0,"id":"1","text":"<p><span style=\"font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', cursive;\">gasdgwere<\/span><\/p>","font":"Comic Sans MS"}]
```

And it is, correctly, of type org.json.JSONArray.

It is only when I attempt to get the JSONArray as a JSONArray (instead of an Object or an Object.toString()) that everything falls to pieces.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("array");
//-OR:
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("array");
//-I have tried both, with the same result
```

I end up getting a StackOverflowError at this point.

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8443-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/path] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntrySet.iterator(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:2329)
    at org.json.JSONObject.writeValue(JSONObject.java:2272)
    at org.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:2337)
    at org.json.JSONObject.writeValue(JSONObject.java:2272)
    at org.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:2337)
    at org.json.JSONObject.writeValue(JSONObject.java:2272)
    at org.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:2337)
    at org.json.JSONObject.writeValue(JSONObject.java:2272)
    //-And on and on....
```

I do not get any sort of errors with similar methods in other parts of the application. The only thing I can think of is that this particular instance contains nested quotes, due to the HTML string from tinyMCE. Also, as you can see when grabbing the array, the slashes in the closing HTML tags are, for some reason, escaped (i.e. < \ / span> instead of < / span>). I am not sure if that has any relevance whatsoever.

Comment: Will getting it as `String` and then doing `new JSONArray(string)` change anything?

Comment: I've executed your code and everything works fine.

Comment: You're executing the write method instead. `at org.json.JSONObject.write(JSONObject.java:2329)`

Comment: @M.Prokhorov - I have just tried this, and unfortunately I still get the same issue.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique - If there is another method other than the write method to retrieve a JSONArray from a JSONObject, I am unaware of it. This is how JSONArrays are taken from JSONObjects throughout the rest of the application.

Comment: @SHornby, that is not possible for the array string you posted here. The array does not contain any kind of loops.

Comment: The JsonArray does not seem to be the cause of this error. Is there any other place you are doing any Map handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it turns out this was entirely my fault. I assumed that the particular lines I posted were the cause of this error, due to the fact that I had quite a difficult time trying to escape the JSON properly.

But it turns out that because my Tomcat logs did not specify the exact line of my class, I wrongly assumed that it was that particular JSONObject causing the error. No, it turned out a little further along in my method, I had this little gem:

```
JSONObject jResponse = new JSONObject();
jResponse.put("response", jResponse);
```

Yes. It was a very simple error that I made the wrong assumption on. I am not sure how I missed this. Thank you everyone for your input, and I shall now go hide in my corner of shame.